# Using relativistic QFT to compute energy levels

Tags: quantum-field-theory, perturbation-theory

I've taken a year of QFT so far, and although there seems to be a lot of attention paid to scattering amplitudes and decay rates and perhaps bound states, I view computing energy spectra as certainly another important problem to solve. For a very simple case, I was wondering how the energy spectrum of electromagnetic fields in a closed cavity is corrected by QFT. Naively it's just a harmonic oscillator, but when we get close to the Schwinger Limit we'll start seeing shifts, right? And to tree level, how would I actually go about computing those corrections? I realized I had very little idea. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by energy spectrum? Are you asking about nonlinear corrections to the classical electromagnetic field? If so it might be useful to look at what Schwinger actually did.

Comment: As in, what the energy levels actually accessible as resonant modes within a given cavity? (Somewhat) equivalently, what are the frequencies that resonate in a given cavity? Classically these are that the frequencies and linearly spaced (and inversely proportional to cavity size), and energies are the squares of those. So yes, I'm asking how you would go about computing the nonlinear corrections to these.

Comment: Well I think you realize that the ordinary point of view in QFT deals with photons, which are different from the coherent field states you are after. I don't think I can give a good answer, but I think Landau's textbook on QED dealt with modifications to the Maxwell equations due to the polarization tensor and presumably that's what Schwinger did too. In a more modern approach, the effective action (see e.g. Peskin's textbook) tells you how the classical action is modified by quantum corrections.

Comment: Alright, I might go take a look at those sources then later. Still hoping someone can answer more thoroughly (or explain to me if I'm confused and this question doesn't even make sense), but thank very much for the pointers!

Comment: No problem, I think actually your question has a well defined answer in how the polarization tensor (that fermion loop correction, which you've probably seen) shifts the poles of the gauge field propagator in a finite volume. Those poles are the resonant states. Good luck!